# Unable to install psycopg2 on shared server (Linux) using SSH. Says, error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: linux, postgresql, gcc, google-analytics-api, psycopg2

I am on a shared server of a reputed web hosting company and here are the details of the version of the Linux I am on. I am adding all the commands here so that solution providers have all the information before answering.

```
$ uname -a
Linux somehosting.com 2.6.32-673.8.1.lve1.4.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 10 08:57:30 EST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-673.8.1.lve1.4.3.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@build.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Feb 10 08:57:30 EST 2016

$ cat /etc/*release*
CloudLinux Server release 6.8 (Oleg Makarov)
CloudLinux Server release 6.8 (Oleg Makarov)
cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:6:ga:server
```

**What I am trying to acheive?**

I need to install psycopg2 on my system.

**What all I have done till now?**

The oauth2client requires Python 2.7 or Python 3+, but my shared hosting provided me with Python 2.6. So, until now, I have successfully installed Python 3.5.3 and Pip locally on my shared server.

**What step I am on now?**

Right now, I am installing psycopg2 through source on my system (details of the system are mentioned in the beginning)

**What problem I am facing?**

Please see the following to know the issue.

```
[myname psycopg2-2.6.2]$ python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6.2 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09030F -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/amanka5/python/Python-3.5.2/Include -I/home/amanka5/python/Python-3.5.2 -I. -I/usr/pgsql-9.3/include -I/usr/pgsql-9.3/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
./psycopg/psycopg.h:31:22: error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:29:
./psycopg/connection.h:98: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PGconn’
./psycopg/connection.h:135: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
./psycopg/connection.h:137: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
./psycopg/connection.h:138: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
./psycopg/connection.h:142: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PGconn’
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:30:
./psycopg/cursor.h:63: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PGresult’
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:31:
./psycopg/green.h:63: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:32:
./psycopg/lobject.h:29:28: error: libpq/libpq-fs.h: No such file or directory
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:32:
./psycopg/lobject.h:49: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘Oid’
./psycopg/lobject.h:55: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘Oid’
./psycopg/lobject.h:55: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘Oid’
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:38:
./psycopg/error.h:38: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PGresult’
psycopg/psycopgmodule.c: In function ‘psyco_register_type’:
psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:154: error: ‘cursorObject’ has no member named ‘string_types’
psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:161: error: ‘connectionObject’ has no member named ‘string_types’
psycopg/psycopgmodule.c: In function ‘psyco_libcrypto_threads_init’:
psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:191: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PQinitOpenSSL’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

**What answers I am looking for?**

I am receiving this gcc problem, but a basic hello world program in C outputs perfect. I have read almost all the answers here on stackoverflow, but I could not find answer for my problem anywhere. I even tried to install psycopg2 using pip and it gives the same error as described above. So, what is the solution to this problem? I am unable to figure it out and need help. Without psycopg2, I won't be able to make connection to my PostgreSQL v9.3 database, which I need real bad.

***Some other relevant details (My gcc version)***

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC)
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is that the compilation fails due to a missing library: `libpq-dev`.

You can see that in the following log-messages:

```
gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6.2 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09030F -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/amanka5/python/Python-3.5.2/Include -I/home/amanka5/python/Python-3.5.2 -I. -I/usr/pgsql-9.3/include -I/usr/pgsql-9.3/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
./psycopg/psycopg.h:31:22: error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
```

To fix that you need to install postgresql developer-libraries. On Redhat-like Linux the package is called `postgresql-devel`. The following command will install the missing libraries:

```
yum install postgresql-devel
```

Comment: Yes, I realised this, but forgot to mention while writing my question. I found this solution on other stackoverflow answers too which were not entirely related to my problem, but unfortunately, even this doesn't work. Please see the code below. I need root access for this. Do we have any other option to install this?

`$ yum install postgresql-devel`
`Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin, security
*Note* CloudLinux Network repositories are not listed below. You must run this command as root to access CLN repositories.
You need to be root to perform this command.`